# Is there a way to bypass "returning reference to local variable" problem?

Tags: c++

I have a homework exercise. I'm almost sure it's unsolvable the way they ask it. However, I'm interested if you guys have any solution for the problem mentioned below because it seems like something that often occurs.

The description is not long, so I share it with you below:

> A matrix S ∈ R n×n is skewsymmetric if it holds that S(Transpose) =
>   −S. Derive from the class SquareMatrix from the lecture the class
>   SkewSymmetricMatrix. Use a vector of length n(n − 1)/2 to store the
>   matrix entries. Implement constructors, type casting and a suitable
>   access to the coefficients.

The problem occurs while trying to provide the access, because the virtual access method defined in SquareMatrix returns a reference.

```
const double& SquareMatrix::operator()( int j, int k ) const
{
    assert( j >= 0 && j < m );
    assert( k >= 0 && k < n );
    return coeff[ j + k * m ];
}
```

However, I can't return reference to the not stored variables. The following code is just for demonstrating my problem. In this case the ***j > k*** block would obviously not work.

```
const double& SkewSymmetricMatrix::operator()( int j, int k ) const
{
    assert( j >= 0 && j < size() );
    assert( k >= 0 && k < size() );
    if( j < k )
    {
        const double* coeff = getCoeff();
        return coeff[ j * ( j - 1 ) / 2 + k ];
    }
    else if ( j > k )
    {
        const double* coeff = getCoeff();
        return -coeff[ k * ( k - 1 ) / 2 + j ];
    }
    else
    {
        return const_zero;
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions that how to provide a proper access operator while trying to reduce the use of memory by

1. storing less elements
2. and calculating the non-stored
   desired elements from the actually stored ones?

Comment: On many modern 64-bit systems `double&` uses the same amount of memory as `double`, so copying a `double` is fine both in terms of speed and memory use. However, you need to return a `double&` if you want the caller to be able to modify the value.

Comment: The "workaround" is to return a value, not a reference.

Comment: Store the calculated value in a private class member, and return a reference to it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: By storing a calculated value in a private class member, this won't work as intended: `my_square_matrix(2, 1) = 42;`.

Comment: @pts It's a const reference.

Comment: @pts - that isn't possible anyway, given the `const` qualifiers on the function and its return type.

Comment: I have a solution that is technically compliant, and won't produce UB

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, I'd recommend putting in a comment explaining why *just in case*. You never know for sure how it will be received.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, pts, David Schwartz: This (private temp member) is not allowed here. If you use a reference to a private member, the value changes at next call. If the caller uses: double& val1 = my_square_matrix(2, 1); double& val2 = my_square_matrix(3, 1); double sum = val1 + val2; The result will be val2+val2, not val1+val2, because the wrong value is referenced.

Comment: @Anton -  The references you mention need to be `const`.  The thing is, this question seeks a work-around for a broken design decision (derived class overiding an inherited function that returns `const` reference when the derived class structure is optimised so there may be no object to return) and then people are quibbling about the need to have an object so a reference can be returned.   Yes, that forces flaws on any solution.   But is unreasonable to expect a work-around for a flawed design to have no flaws - since, a workaround, by definition does not correct a flaw, it incorporates it.

Comment: @Peter - You’re correct about the const, but not about the flaws. You CAN fulfill the requirements, but you must accept the need of additional storage! Never reuse a referenced value, the costs are exorbitant because of error prone code. Double memory usage is low cost against. Make a second member vector, but leave it empty. Always if you access a not existent element, check the vector (and resize it once to n(n-1)/2 if empty, but never to another size!), and write the value at the desired position. Then, return a reference to this position.

Comment: @Peter - If you reference a private reused member, this is always a very bad idea! Instead, you could also implement a get-method and throw an exception, if the parentheses-operator is called.

Comment: I have summarized my comments to an answer.

Comment: Because there isn't a comment saying this explicitly: this is a horrible assignment and cannot be implemented in a reasonable way.

Answer (score 1):

One idea in comments was **using a temporary private member and return a reference to it. That would be a really bad idea**:

If you use a reference to a private member, the value changes at next call. If the caller uses:

```
const double& val1 = my_square_matrix(2, 1);
const double& val2 = my_square_matrix(3, 1);
double sum = val1 + val2;
```

The result will be `val2 + val2`, not `val1 + val2`, because the wrong value is referenced.

**But there are two solutions to fulfill the requirements:**

1. **Implement a get-method and throw an exception, if the parentheses-operator is called.**
2. **Make a second member vector**, but leave it empty. Always **if you access a not existent element, check the vector** (and resize it once to n(n-1)/2 if empty, but never to another size!), and **write the value at the desired position**. Then, **return a reference to this position**.
   Only once resize the vector, because it can allocate new memory if resized, so old references would get invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem requires using a vector of `n*(n-1)/2` elements, but it doesn't specify the type of element that that vector should contain.

> A matrix S ∈ R n×n is skewsymmetric if it holds that S(Transpose) = −S. Derive from the class SquareMatrix from the lecture the class SkewSymmetricMatrix. Use a vector of length n(n − 1)/2 to store the matrix entries. Implement constructors, type casting and a suitable access to the coefficients.

Given that we have no capacity to change the interface given by the `SquareMatrix` class, we will have to resort to solving this problem with a solution that is ***technically*** compliant, even if it doesn't follow the spirit of the professor's request (which is impossible).

Each element of the vector will contain *two* `double` values, one corresponding to the element `m_ij`, and the other corresponding to `m_ji` (for `i < j`). We can call these the left and right elements:

```
struct mirror {
    double left; 
    double right; 

    void assignLeft(double val) {
        left = val; 
        right = -val;
    }
    void assignRight(double val) {
        left = -val;
        right = val;
    }
};
```

We may use a vector of `n*(n-1) / 2` elements of type `mirror`, and we return either the `left` or `right` members based on which index is asked for:

```
const double& SkewSymmetricMatrix::operator()( int j, int k ) const
{
    assert( j >= 0 && j < size() );
    assert( k >= 0 && k < size() );
    if( j < k )
    {
        const mirror* coeff = getCoeff();
        return coeff[ j * ( j - 1 ) / 2 + k ].left;
    }
    else if ( j > k )
    {
        const mirror* coeff = getCoeff();
        return coeff[ k * ( k - 1 ) / 2 + j ].right;
    }
    else
    {
        return const_zero;
    }
}
```

**Such is life in Moscow.**

Comment: I would never have assigned a problem like this, unless trying to demonstrate pitfalls of poor design.    If I *had* assigned a problem like this, this solution would be marked incorrect, since it is introducing new unwarranted assumptions about what is possible  (e.g. about what `getCoeff()` is, and ability to change its signature).

Answer (score -1):

If you want `const double& SquareMatrix::operator()(int j, int k) const { ... }` to override a virtual method, thus keep returning a `const double&`, then I don't know how to do it.

If you are allowed to change the signature, then create

```
class ValueAccessor {
  double &value;
  bool is_negated;
 public:
  ValueAccessor& operator=(double other) {
    value = is_negated ? -other : other;
    return *this;
  }
  operator double() const {
    return is_negated ? -value : value;
  }
  ...
};
```

, and return a `ValueAccessor` from `operator()(...)`.

Comment: This won't work because the class is overriding a virtual method in a different class, and the question asker does not have control over the signature of the base class method